# Getting some files into a Git repo, that I've set to ignore

Tags: git

I'm still very new at Git. I'm working on a small website. I read somewhere that Git doesn't do well with binary files. This website has some image files as well as PDFs, so I created a .gitignore and put the various image file types into it, as well as *.PDF. So, now that I've got the .gitignore file set up as I'd like it, I want to put those image and PDF files into the website. (I'm copying them over from the TFVC repo.) What I don't know is if I should simply copy them using File Explorer, or if I should use some Git command or something from within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Wait...you _added_ .PDF files to your `.gitignore` but now you want to _add_ them to your repo?  Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: No, I don't want to add them to the repo. Like I said, I don't understand how to handle Git and how I should proceed. Ultimately, what I want is to just add the files to the project in VS Code, not to the Git repo. However, because I don't understand this with respect to how one is supposed to work with Code and Git, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use Git commands or just copy the files into the project and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added those files to your `.gitignore`, that also mean you did a `git rm --cached those_files`, commit and push, in order to record their deletion, and stop tracking them.

From there, getting those same files into your website is a deployment process: use any tool you want to copy them from a source (here your TVFS repo, which is not a Git repo I suppose, considering you just ignore those files in a Git repo), and the destination folder.

Comment: Thank you, I believe you've given me enough. I hadn't copied the image and PDF files into the repo. I am at the point of wanting to put theme into the file structure that VS Code works with. Just wasn't sure if I had to follow some convention of adding them via Git or just copy them into place from the TFVC repo. Looks like all I need to do is copy them over. That way they'll be available when testing and won't be in the Git. (I hope I've correctly understood what you've said.)

Comment: @Rod Yes, that is the general idea.